# ListPlot with different color options

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let's define some sample data

```
data = {{-3, -1}, {-2, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-0.2, -0.2}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5},
        {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}};
```

and create the corresponding list plot

```
L0 = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
```

[image]

Now, I want the following: change the color at different segments of the thick line. For example:

- for $-2.4 < x < -1.1$ ---> red thick
- for $-0.2 < x < 0.94$ ---> blue thick
- for $2.22 < x < 3.4$ ---> green thick
- in all other cases ---> black thick

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
The real data contain thousands of pairs which cannot be separated into sections. Only the intervals on the x axis are known. So, I want a
continuous line with different colors in each segment.

What would be an elegant and quick way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The simplest? Separate the data into sections, run `ListPlot[sectioned, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Green], Directive[Thick, Black]}]` where the styles in `PlotStyle` are in the correct order.

Comment: Should be doable with the judicious use of `ColorFunction` and `Piecewise[]`.

Comment: @rcollyer It's not that simple! The real data contain thousands of pairs which cannot be separated into sections. Only the intervals on the $x$ axis are known. So, I want a continuous line with different colors in each segment.

Comment: @J.M. i thought that too but when you try it, Mathematica blends the colors over and does not make a sharp border..

Comment: You're correct, the boundary points represent a problem. I like the `Mesh` solutions propose below. Far simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = {{-3, -1}, {-2, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-0.2, -0.2}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5},
        {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}};

ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotStyle ->Thick, 
 (* MeshFunctions -> {# &},*) 
 Mesh -> {{-2.4, -1.1, -0.2, 0.94, 2.22, 3.4}}, 
 MeshStyle -> PointSize[0], 
 MeshShading -> Riffle[{Red, Blue, Green}, Black, {1, -1, 2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great answer! What if there is no gap between blue and green? Will it still work or there will be a black point?

Comment: I like that. I wondered why you used `MeshFunctions->{#&}`. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @BlacKow, this works only for the case with no overlaps. If the list of breakpoints have duplicate elements as in `{-2.4, -1.1, -0.2, 0.94, .94, 3.4}` then you can use `MeshShading->{Black, Red, Black, Blue, Green}`

Comment: @JulienKluge, good point; the default value of `MeshFunctions` is `#&`, so it is redundant.

Comment: What does the {1, -1, 2} at the end mean?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, it inserts `Black` in every other position in the list `{Red,Blue, Green}` starting from position one. Without it `Riffle[{Red,Blue, Green}, Black]` would give `{Red, Black,Blue, Black, Green}`. See [Riffle](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Riffle.html)

Comment: Alternatively: `ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], Mesh -> {{-2.4, -1.1, -0.2, 0.94, 2.22, 3.4}}, MeshStyle -> None, MeshShading -> Riffle[{Red, Blue, Green}, Automatic, {1, -1, 2}]]`.

Answer (score 3):

We use an unscaled [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) with a [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) which uses your definitions. Interestingly one have to alter the Mesh-settings to allow a sharp color-border otherwise it will blend over.

```
L0=ListPlot[data,Joined->True,PlotStyle->Thick,ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},Piecewise[{{Red,-2.4<x<-1.1},{Blue,-0.2<x<0.94},{Green,2.22<x<3.4}},Black]],ColorFunctionScaling->False,Mesh->200,MeshShading->{Automatic},MeshStyle->None]
```

> [image]

Comment: Is it just my impression or the middle part is not so smooth? I see it like a bunch of dots...

Comment: Uhm well, it looks good to me on my machine. Try to Increase the Mesh-option. Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: The Mesh-option does not have any affect. Try to enlarge the image you posted and you will see that the middle line is not a real straight line! It looks like a join of dots or something else!

Comment: I'm on OSX, MMA 11.0.0.0 and I see the same behavior, but only for this answer. Other options show a smooth curve.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative you can follow up idea of separation. Since we don't know if you have the endpoints of your regions in your data set , we can use `Interpolation` and then break it up into several pieces.

```
limitF[f_, {xmin_, xmax_}] := 
  Piecewise[{{f[#], xmax > # > xmin}}, Infinity] &;
data = {{-3, -1}, {-2, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-0.2, -0.2}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 
    0.5}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}};
fun = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
separated = 
  limitF[fun, #] & /@ {{-2.4, -1.1}, {-0.2, 0.94}, {2.2, 3.4}};
```

So `separated` is list of functions that present `fun` in different regions.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{fun[x]}~Join~(#[x] & /@ separated)], {x, -3, 4}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Black], Directive[Thick, Red], 
   Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Green]}]
```

[image]