# ListPlot with different color options part II

Tags: plotting, graphics

In a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128383/listplot-with-different-color-options), we saw how to change the colors in different segments of the `ListPLot` when the intervals on the $x$ axis are given.

My question now is the following:

For the same test data how to change the color of the line in different segments according to the value of $y$. For example:

```
 data = {{-3, -1}, {-2, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-0.2, -0.2}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5},
        {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}};
```

- for $-0.92 < y < -0.5$ ---> red thick
- for $0.12 < y < 0.94$ ---> blue thick
- for $1.32 < y < 1.45$ ---> green thick
- in all other cases ---> black thick

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
The real data contain thousands of pairs which cannot be separated into sections. Only the intervals on the y axis are known. So, I want a
continuous line with different colors in each segment.

What would be an elegant and quick way to do this?

Comment: You can still use kglr's answer: add the setting `MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}` and make the necessary adjustments in the `Mesh` setting.

Comment: @J.M. You are a life saver! Please post a quick reply, so as to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MeshShading`, e.g.

```
ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 Mesh -> {{-0.92, -0.5, 0.12, 0.94, 1.32, 1.45}}, MeshStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> {Black, Red, Black, Blue, Black, Green, Black}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02]]
```

[image]